# Random number and operator being generated is the same as previous random number and operator generated

Tags: java, random, switch-statement, operator-keyword

> Im trying to generate a random number and operator  for every instance : "System.out.println (firstNumbereasy + operatorSwitch + secondNumbereasy) but the same operator and number is being generated each time.

My main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);{
```

my code for generating random number and operator is

```
    Random randN = new Random();

 int firstNumbereasy; //declaring variables  for easy mode
 int secondNumbereasy;

 firstNumbereasy = randN.nextInt(11) + 1; 

 secondNumbereasy= randN.nextInt(firstNumbereasy - 1); 



Random operatorChoice = new Random();
int operator = operatorChoice.nextInt(3);

 int b = (0);
 int c = (0);
 
String operatorSwitch;

     
    switch (operator){// generates random operators

        case 0: operatorSwitch= "+";
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy+secondNumbereasy);
            break;
        case 1: operatorSwitch= "-";
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy-secondNumbereasy);
            break;
        case 2: operatorSwitch= "*";
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy*secondNumbereasy);
            break;
        case 3: operatorSwitch= "/";
            c = (int) (firstNumbereasy/secondNumbereasy);
            
        default: operatorSwitch="";
    
    }
```

but when i try to print it with :

```
int selection;
 


 System.out.println("-----------------------");
    System.out.println("Choose a mode");// displays mode user can pick
    System.out.println("1.     Easy");
    System.out.println("2.     Hard");
    System.out.println("3.     Easy Elimination");
    System.out.println("4.     Hard Elimination");
    
    

    selection = scanner.nextInt(); // reads what mode user picks 
       

        switch(selection) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("Question 1, what is " + firstNumbereasy +operatorSwitch+ secondNumbereasy );
         b= scanner.nextInt();
          
         System.out.println("Question 2, what is " + firstNumbereasy + operatorSwitch + secondNumbereasy);
        b = scanner.nextInt();
        case 2:
```

The same random number and operator for every time i use :`System.out.println("Question 1 what is " +firstNumbereasy + operatorSwitch + secondNumbereasy);` is the same

Comment: The random number generation happens when you call the method `randN.nextInt`. When you then assign the result of that call to a variable it will save the result of that one single call in that variable. Accessing that variable will not call the `nextInt` method again. That is something you have to do yourself.

Comment: Or to make it short: `int x = randN.nextInt(11); System.out.println(x); System.out.println(x);` will generate a single random number and print that same number twice.  `int x = randN.nextInt(11); System.out.println(x); x = randN.nextInt(11);System.out.println(x);` will generate a random number, print it, then generate a new random number and print that new number.

Comment: Thanks!!! I  But how would i generate a new random operator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you're generating the values of firstNumbereasy, secondNumbereasy and operator only once in your code, if you'd like to have them changed for each question you need to re-run the following lines of code every time:

```
int firstNumbereasy = randN.nextInt(11) + 1;; //declaring variables  for easy mode
int secondNumbereasy = randN.nextInt(firstNumbereasy - 1);

int operator = operatorChoice.nextInt(3);
```

my personal suggestion would be to extract this to a function as it's going to repeat a lot it seems

Comment: When i try to use : int operator = operatorChoice.nextInt(3); to try draw another random  operator it insteads uses the operator (*, -, /,+) to print the solution instead of the string of the operator,